# PhpStorm 2016.3 - tabs converted to spaces

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using tabs to indent my code, but also to indent inline comments.
While in JavaScript everything works as expected [(JS example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6nsH.png), in PHP  my tabs in front of comments are replaced with spaces, while the leading tabs stay intact. ([PHP example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD23A.png))

Actually during typing it inserts the tabs (and everything is fine), but as soon as I use `Code | Reformat Code` tabs are changed to spaces.

In `Settings | Editor | Code Style`  I use the same for both - JavaScript and PHP.

(*use tab character / all indents 4 spaces / keep indents on empty lines*)

Do I miss any setting? Anyone got the same problem or a solution?

Comment: 1) Do you have EditorConfig plugin installed & enabled? if so -- check settings in your `.editorconfig` files (project root etc); 2) Maybe you have `Detect indents automatically per file` (this kind of option enabled)? 3) Try resetting your Code Style to Default schema and see how it will behave there.

Comment: hi lazy, thx for fast reply. And no, no EditorConfig, `detect intends` makes no difference. I also switched to default settings and just enabled `use tab character` in PHP settings, still the same. Do you have the same behavior in your php storm?